# Showing that a particular f'(x) is not continuous at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

[image]

I really dont understand what the highlighted section of this proof is trying to show. I feel I am missing some theorem of which it is trying to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the highlighted area of the proof is saying is:

> For any $\delta > 0$ and for every value $y\in[-\frac12, \frac32]$ there exists such a $x, |x|<\delta$, that $f'(x) = y$.

This statement can then easily be shown to prove that the statement

> For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists such a $\delta>0$ that for all $x$, $|x-0|<\delta$, the inequality $|f'(x) - f'(0)| \leq \epsilon$ holds.

is not true. Since this is the statement $f'$ is continuous at $0$, that is what you need.

Comment: No, the highlighted area is explaining why f' is NOT continuous.

Comment: @5xum see my comment underneath the question

Comment: @1234 The function is $\frac{1}{2} + 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$. The $1/2$ factor shifts the "reachable interval" up to $[-1/2, +3/2]$.

Comment: Apologies I still cant see why $f'$ is not continuous at $0$

Comment: @1234 That's because you're not reading my question, you're nitpicking it. Read the first highlited statement I wrote. Do you agree it is true? Read the second. Do you agrree that it is what you need to prove? If the answer to both questions is yes, then try to prove statement 2 from statement 1. Otherwise, ask me about the part you don't understand.

Comment: I agree with the first statement. I cannot see how to prove the second, moreover Im not trying to nitpick but I think it should be $|f'(x)-f'(0)| \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @1234 There you are correct, I fixed my answer. Now, I asked two questions and you only answered one. So once again: (1) Do you agree that the first statement is true? (2) Do you agree that the second statement is what you need to prove?

Comment: Yes and Yes, but cannot see how for the second yes

Comment: @1234 Well, go by definition. That is: What do you have to prove in order to prove that statement $2$ is not true? (what is the inverse of the statement?)

Answer (score 1):

It is a "lazy" way to state that $\liminf_{x \to 0} f'(x)=-\frac12$ and $\limsup_{x \to 0} f'(x)=\frac12$.
The sentence essentially means that $f'(x)$ oscillates between $-1/2$ and $1/2$ as $x$ approaches zero, and hence no limit exists for $f'(x)$. In particular, $f'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Surely though $f'$ could still be continuous even if it oscillates between $-1/2$ and $1/2$?

Comment: @1234 Not if it oscilates between two values on an arbitrarily small interval...

Comment: How can one show this, I do not feel it is intuitive?